# Progress bar on uploading with jQuery-File-Upload (blueimp) doesn't get updated anymore

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using the https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload script and until now I was able to dynamicly update my bootstrap progresse-bar with the following jQuery-File-Upload snippet:

```
            progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
            console.log("progress: " + progress);
        },
```

The html for this progress-bar looks like:

```
            <div id="progress" class="progress progress-striped">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%"></div>
            </div>
```

But now this progress-bar don't get filled, it always remains at 0%. I added that console.log above to debug this and in the console everything looks good. I get all the "progress: 1" and so on messages.

So why the progressbar div doesn't get updated anymore?

Thanks

**update: Had to change the jquery line to

```
$('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
```